# Use %20 instead of + for space in python query parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written the following python script, using python requests (http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```py
import requests

payload = {'key1': 'value  1', 'key2': 'value 2'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
r = requests.get(
    "http://example.com/service",
    params=payload,
    headers=headers, 
    auth=("admin", "password")
)
```

If I look at the access log of the server, the incoming request is

```
/service?key1=value++1&key2=value+2
```

However, the server expects ...`value%20%201&`...

I have read that using a + as a placeholder for a space is part of content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but clearly I have requested application/json.

Anybody know how to use `%20` as a space in query parameters of pythons requests?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  Did you just go with `urllib`, or modify the server or something?

Comment: I honestly do not know anymore. Quite a while ago, and I do not have access to the sources anymore

Comment: I am still stuck on this as well. Bummer

Comment: @Bryce check my answer, the simple solution is to override  **urllib.quote_pluse** with **urllib.quote**

Answer (score 34):

To follow up on @WeaselFox's answer, they introduced a patch that accepts a `quote_via` keyword argument to `urllib.parse.urlencode`.  Now you could do this:

```
import requests
import urllib

payload = {'key1': 'value  1', 'key2': 'value 2'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)
r = requests.get("http://example.com/service", params=params, headers=headers,
    auth=("admin", "password"))
```

Answer (score 2):

**PYTHON 2.7**

- Override the **urllib.quote_pluse** with **urllib.quote**
- The urlencoder uses urllib.quote_pluse to encode the data.

---

### code

```
import requests
import urllib
urllib.quote_plus=urllib.quote # A fix for urlencoder to give %20 
payload = {'key1': 'value  1', 'key2': 'value 2'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
param = urllib.urlencode(payload) #encodes the data
r = requests.get("http://example.com/service", params=param, headers=headers, 
             auth=("admin", "password"))
```

### output

```
the output for param = urllib.urlencode(payload)
'key2=value%202&key1=value%20%201'
```

Answer (score 1):

try it.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlencode(params)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlencode'

Comment: @Prometheus the answer refers to Python 2. In Python 3 it's `urllib.parse.urlencode(params)` (import with `import urllib.parse`)

Answer (score 1):

I only find [urllib.parse.quote](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) , which can replace space to `%20` .

But `quote` could not convert a dict.

so, We must use `quote` to transform dict in advance.

---

```
#for python3
from urllib.parse import quote

payload = {'key1': 'value  1', 'key2': 'value 2'}

newpayload = {}
for (k, v) in payload.items():
    newpayload[quote(k)] = quote(v)
print(newpayload)
#print result: {'key1': 'value%20%201', 'key2': 'value%202'}
# Now, you can use it in requests
```

Comment: Tried swapping spaces for %20 in my payload. The request parser then URLencoded the percent symbols so "this%20that" turned into "this%2520that" - so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a known bug/issue in python :

http://bugs.python.org/issue13866

I think you will have to go around this issue using `urllib` and `urllib2` and avoid requests. look at the bug reports for some tips on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

We can use urllib2.Request to call url

```
import urllib2

send_params = {'key1': 'value  1', 'key2': 'value 2'}
new_send_params = []
for (k, v) in send_params.items():
    new_send_params.append(k + "=" + urllib2.quote(v))

url = 'http://example.com/service?'+ '&'.join(new_send_params)
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print "Request URL: " + url
#Request URL: http://example.com/service?key1=value%20&key2=value%202
print response.read()
#Python Master Request handler 2016-07-04 16:05:19.928132 . Your request path is  /service?key1=value%20&key2=value%202
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def to_query_string(params):
    return urlencode(params, doseq=True).replace('+', '%20')
```

---

You could pass a string to `params` instead of a dictionary, and manually handle the spaces.

Maybe something along the lines of

```py
def to_query_string(p, s=''):
    for k in p:
        v = p[k]
        if isinstance(v, str):
            s += f'{k}={v}&'.replace(' ', '%20')
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            s += f'{k}={v}&'
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                s += f'{k}={i}&'
    return s[:-1]  # remove last '&'
```


which can be used as

```py
min = 10
max = 30
params = {'query': f'score between {min} and {max}', 'limit': 1, 'information': ['name', 'location']}
response = get('/api/dogs', params=to_query_string(params))
```

Answer (score 0):

`requests` uses internally `quote()` from `urllib.parse`

```py
import requests
from requests.utils import quote

url='https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/'
requests.get(url, params='q='+quote('rue du Jura')).url
```

`https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=rue%20du%20Jura`

If you give a str/byte (and not a dict), `requests` don't encode you params