# Passing parameters with spaces to url in requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm requesting data from an API which allows for additional filtering by passing extra params to the URL. I'm doing that but getting back the unfiltered report.

The code I'm using is

```
import requests

# prepare the url
API_KEY = '234-1234-1234-123-42134'
BASE_URL = 'https://hq.appsflyer.com/export/{appsflyer_id}/{endpoint}/{version}'

appsflyer_id = 'id123456789'
endpoint = 'in_app_events_report'
version = 'v5'
start_date = '2018-09-13'
end_date = '2018-09-19'
media_source = 'Apple Search Ads'
event_name = 'event name with spaces'

url = BASE_URL.format(appsflyer_id=appsflyer_id, endpoint=endpoint, version=version)

# additional filtering
params = {
    'api_token': API_KEY, 
    'from': start_date, 'to': end_date,
    'media_source': media_source,
    'event_name': event_name,
}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

The problem is that the 'media_source' and 'event_name' params aren't being recognised, it seems, since I'm getting back **all** media sources and **all** event names.

I tried to inspect the URL but running

```
r.url
```

returns

https://rawdata.appsflyer.com/export/token/lego_test_id123456789_non_organic_in_app_events_2018-09-13_2018-09-19_JTSWQ

which is odd because that isn't the url I'm building.

I tried using this code

```
params = {
    'api_token': API_KEY_STITCHFIX, 
    'from': start_date, 'to': end_date,
    'media_source': media_source,
    'event_name': event_name,
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823965/use-20-instead-of-for-space-in-python-query-parameters) answer but it also didn't work.

The API docs are [here](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs#Raw), if that helps.

My questions are then:

1. Why is requests returning this URL?
2. How can I correctly pass the parameters in the request?

Comment: How should the url work? For me when I have something like this: `sQuery.replace(' ','+')` sQuery is just replaced by the string. For each space you could switch it to the appropriate symbol (`+`,`%`,etc) You can add everything variable wise and then use `url = string(url).replace(' ', `symbol`) `

Comment: Not sure I understand. Spaces are usually encoded with `%20` but I thought requests did that automatically.

Comment: No, usually you have to do them yourself sadly(At least from my experience) 

Also while spaces tend to be encoded with `%20` sites such as YouTube use `+` and some just use `%`

Comment: But could you also give an example of the output you would like to have? I think it would help out a bit. Reason for this is you have the `_` appearing but also in `endpoint` you have it defined in the code as `in_app_events_report` so its kind of hard to tell what should and shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm going through the docs to see how they encode spaces. Also, the `in_app_events_name` is defined by them which is probably why it has no spaces. The values for `media_source` and `event_name` are user-defined and in my case they both contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Have you tried using `replace()` and see how that works out as a little test ( using `url.replace(' ','%20')` should do the trick as all spaces are removed, and the correct format for the site `%20` is what they are switched to). If this doesn't work I will be sure to continue finding ways to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Trying `url.replace(' ','%20')` would probably not work because the full url is only built in `r = requests.get(url, params=params)` and the problematic part seems to be the params. I did try hardcoding the URL and replacing the spaces with %20 but I'm just getting the col headers back. I know I should be getting data because I downloaded the same request via their console and there are results for that request.

Comment: Ah okay seeing that is where the url is built your right in saying `replace()` won't work. I don't know how I hadn't noticed that before. Its odd that submitting the request doesn't give the correct response even when hard coded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180444/discussion-between-mcansado-and-narus).